# JS/Angular/Places API - document.getElementById(key).value issues with form inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places API to auto populate locations/destinations into a form once a user searches. I have the form auto populating properly, but when I go to submit the form into my database, the object goes through as undefined each time. My issue occurs when I try and submit my form after the auto populate takes place.

What's weird is that if I manually copy and paste the same information that is auto populated into the same text fields, the form is submitted and data is input into my database with no problem.

Any ideas on why this is happening? If I'm auto populating the correct values into the form, shouldn't the values be binded to my ng-model when I go to the controller?

HTML ========================

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h3>Markers</h3>
            <form ng-submit="addMarker(newMarker)">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Add a new marker: </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" ng-model="newMarker.title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" ng-model="newMarker.address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Category" ng-model="newMarker.category">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="URL (optional)" ng-model="newMarker.url">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Message (optional)" ng-model="newMarker.description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="list" placeholder="Add to a list (optional)" ng-model="newMarker.list">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude" disabled="true" ng-model="newMarker.latitude">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" disabled="true" ng-model="newMarker.longitude">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS ==========================

```
// Get the HTML input element for search for the autocomplete search box
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

// Create the autocomplete object.
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

// Event Listener for a Places API search
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var contentString = '<p><b>'+place.name+'</b></p>'+
                        '<p>'+place.formatted_address+'</p>';
    var pos = {
            lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: place.geometry.location.lng()
        };
    fillInForm(place);
    map.setCenter(pos);
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    });
});

// Auto fill the form from the Places API search
var fillInForm = function(place) {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
    var markerForm = {
            title: place.name,
            address: place.formatted_address,
            coordinates: ""+lat+", "+lng+""
    };
    for (var key in markerForm) {
        document.getElementById(key).value = '';
        document.getElementById(key).disabled = false;
        var val = markerForm[key];
        document.getElementById(key).value = val;
    }
    $scope.markerForm = markerForm;
}

// CREATE NEW MARKER ===============================
$scope.addMarker = function() {
    markersFactory.addMarker($scope.newMarker, function(returnDataFromFactory){
        if(returnDataFromFactory.hasOwnProperty('errors')){
            $scope.newMarkerErrors = returnDataFromFactory.errors;
        } else {
            // console.log(returnDataFromFactory.data);
            $scope.newMarker = {};
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT: Added rest of the container. Previously only provided the form div. Added the pac-input and map div.

Comment: where is your pac-input field in the html you have posted? can you post the code for the same if not there?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen no prob! i omitted it before and just provided the form. I've added the pac-input field to my original post now.

Answer (score 0):

When form elements are getting updated like this (direct DOM manipulation via `document.getElementById` function):

```
for (var key in markerForm) {
    document.getElementById(key).value = '';
    document.getElementById(key).disabled = false;
    var val = markerForm[key];
    document.getElementById(key).value = val;
}
```

Angular is not aware of those changes.

The *Angular way* of [data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) would be to replace `fillInForm` function with:

```
var fillInForm = function (place) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.newMarker.title =  place.name;
       $scope.newMarker.address = place.formatted_address;
       $scope.newMarker.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
       $scope.newMarker.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
    });  
}
```

> `$apply` is needed here since  `place_changed` event is triggered
>   outside of Angular digest loop

Demo: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tRtMTyQynkKcVvhnH90K?p=preview)